# everybody loves somebody in symbolic logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Can I rewrite the sentence "**everybody loves somebody**" as follows:

***∀x(Person(x) -> ∃y(Person(y) ^ Loves(x,y)))***

Comment: That's OK. Are you given any predicate definitions or did you just invent your own?

Comment: The issue with the sentence "everybody loves somebody" in normal language is that is not clear if:  $\tag*{}$
1) All people love at least one person.  $\tag*{}$
2) All people love the same "somebody"; there is someone universally loved. $\tag*{}$   
  
Depending on which of these you mean, the answer to the question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let $Lxy$ be the predicate 'x loves y':

$(\forall x)(\exists y)(Lxy)$

Comment: Extra note: If the domain isn't stated as people only, then you also need a predicate for "x is a person" in order to prevent the sentence from applying to any and all things.

Comment: This is predicate logic with quantifiers, i do not need a domain of discourse. In fact it is a truth of logic that any 2-place predicate satisfies.

Comment: If you are not using a domain of discourse, then the correct answer is $(\forall x)(Px \to (\exists y)(Py \land Lxy))$. $Px$ is the predicate "x is a person", so that we are making it clear that we are talking about "every*one*" and "some*one*", rather than "everything" and "something". $\tag*{}$

Your claim that "it is a truth of logic that any 2-place predicate satisfies" is false, as the two-place predicate "x is older than y" does not satisfy it. This is because a baby born this very instant is not older than anybody.

Comment: Who said you have to love or to be a person in the phrase "everybody loves somebody"? $Lxy\iff$ "x loves y" therefore it is sufficient $(\forall x)(\exists y)(Lxy)$.

Comment: "Everybody" and "somebody" refer to people. If it were instead "everything loves something", *then* $(\forall x)(\exists y)(Lxy)$ would be sufficient.

Comment: Fine, i agree. Then we have, $Hx\iff$ '$x$ is human'. Thus: $(\forall x)(Hx\implies (\exists y)(Hy\land Lxy))$